# Returning a string (or array) from a function in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, function, return

Basically what I want is to return a string from a function (or an array in general).

```
type_string(?) Function_foo(type_string(?) string_foo)
{
     ......
    return String_bar;
}

printf("%s", function_foo(string_foo));
```

This should give me `string_bar` as output. Is that possible? All the questions I've looked at so far, give special usecases and the answers are specific to that.

Comment: Have you tried `char*` ?

Answer (score 2):

Array will not work because if it is out of scope the object will cease to exist (unless allocated dynamically).

But this is fine:

```
char  * foo1()
{
  char *  p= "somestring"
  return p;
}

char  * foo2()
{
  return  "somestring";
}
```

Comment: Using `char*` to point to literals is permitted by the C standard for historical reasons, but that doesn't make it a good idea. `const char*` is self-documenting, use that when the caller must not modify the string.

Answer (score 2):

Strings do not exist as a type in C, they are `char` arrays. An array is basically a pointer to the first element. So, to return a string (or array), you return a pointer:

```
const char *function_foo(const char *string_foo)
{
    const char *String_bar = "return me";

    return String_bar;
}

const char *string_foo = "supply me";
printf("%s", function_foo(string_foo));
```

More information can be found on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string_handling).

Comment: Same comment that I posted under the other answer: prefer `const char*` when returning pointers to string literals.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a `char[]` and return it from a string, you actually get the memory for the `char[]` from the program stack. When your function returns, the `char[]` loses its scope and can contain a garbage value. So you should use `malloc` to locate the `char *`, so you will get memory from the heap, which you will have to `free()` in the calling function.